# missing class while webscraping -having difficulty in making a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am working on a project on 'zomato.com' which shows us the restaurants all over the world. It shows us the menu, the reputation, photos and other much information.

We want to crawl the all  information about 'name, rating_vote, address, cuisine, price' of Melbourne restaurants .

we can fine those information on 'https://www.zomato.com/melbourne/restaurants'

But we have a problem on making a dataframe by integrating all the 5 variables above. The reason why is that some results of the variable 'Price' don't have a value(other 5  variables has 150 values each but price has 144 values).

We should unify the number of results  of each variable to integrate as a dataframe. We need to do this step because we are going to analyze the results of crawling by using excel. We want to give the NA value to the values which don't have any result(the 6 values omitted of prices)

Could you give me an answer how I can give NA values for making all the variables 
in a dataframe

Here is our code.

```
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("writexl")
install.packages("stringr")
install.packages("data.table")
install.packages("tidyr")



library("rvest")
library("dplyr")
library("writexl")
library("stringr")
library("data.table")
library("tidyr")



#url
url <- "https://www.zomato.com/melbourne/restaurants?page="
page <- c(1:941)
zomato_url <- c()


for (i in 1:941){
  zomato_url[i] <- paste0(url,page[i])
}


#variable tp collect
name <- c()
rating_vote <- c()
address <- c()
cuisine <- c()
price <- c()


for(i in 1:10){
  html <- read_html(zomato_url[i])
  name <- c(name, html_nodes(html, ".result-        
            title.hover_feedback.zred.bold.ln24.fontsize0")%>%
            html_text(trim=T))
  rating_vote <- c(rating_vote, html_nodes(html, ".ta-                
                   right.floating.search_result_rating.col-s-4.clearfix")%>%
                   html_text(trim=T))
  address <- c(address, html_nodes(html, ".col-m-16.search-result- 
               address.grey-text.nowrap.ln22")%>%
               html_text(trim=T))
  cuisine <- c(cuisine, html_nodes(html, ".col-s-11.col-m-12.nowrap.pl0")%>%
               html_text(trim=T))
  price <- c(price, html_nodes(html, ".res- 
             cost.clearfix")%>%html_nodes(".col-s-11.col-m-12.pl0")%>%
             html_text(trim=T))
  print(i)
}



#making data frame
outcome <- data.frame(name, rating_vote, address, cuisine, price)


#importing to excel
write_xlsx(outcome, path="C:/Users/helen.DESKTOP- 
          SG9LJPT/Desktop/outcome.xlsx")
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing `html_table(fill=TRUE)` as described [here](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/31) ?

Comment: Can you give me any link where price is not mentioned ?. It could be because of different html node.
Try using xpath and check if you are getting same values.

Comment: https://www.zomato.com/melbourne/restaurants?page=3                                                  This is the link where you can find the node which doesn't mention the price!! thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use one condition before the scrapping.

Use the condition just after title html node. If the price node available under title node then scrap and put in a list followed by appending it into a dataframe.

You can use xpath also, It will be easier to check the condition if you use xpath.